# All variations from the harvest (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, combinatorics

I would like to generate all possible variations without repetition. I have prepared a data set and a query, and the expected result

```
with t as (
  select 'A' as col1 from dual
  union all
  select 'B' as col1 from dual
  union all
  select 'C' as col1 from dual
)
select * from t
```

or

```
 with t as (
      select 'A' as col1, 'B' as col2, 'C' as col3 from dual
    )
    select * from t
```

What do I want to get?:

```
A;
A;B
A;B;C
A;C
B;
B;C
C;
```

the order of the lines is not relevant, the elements do not have an order, so they cannot be: A;B and B;A

It works, but it returns duplicate variations:

```
select sys_connect_by_path( col1, ';' )
from t
connect by nocycle col1 <> prior col1
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I use the 11xe version.

Comment: There goes recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the code below:

```sql
with t as (
  select 'A' as col1 from dual
  union all
  select 'B' as col1 from dual
  union all
  select 'C' as col1 from dual
) 
select substr(sys_connect_by_path( col1, ';' ),2)
from t
connect by nocycle col1 < prior col1;
```